# Deployer - composer does not work

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I use deployer to deploy a laravel application. Everything works fine except the composer. There is always the message

> Nothing to install or update

When i open the same folder via terminal, the composer installs all the packages.

Do i miss something in the deploy.php file?

deploy.php

```
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';
require 'recipe/npm.php';
require 'vendor/deployer/recipes/recipe/cachetool.php';



// Project name
set('application', '******');

// Project repository
set('repository', '********');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true);

// Shared files/dirs between deploys
add('shared_files', []);
add('shared_dirs', []);

// Writable dirs by web server
add('writable_dirs', []);


// Hosts

host('*********')
    ->user('******')
    ->port(******)
    ->identityFile('********')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/**********/{{application}}');

// Tasks

task('build', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} && build');
});

task('npm:build', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} && npm run production');
});

task('deploy:composer_install', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} ');
    run('composer install');
})->desc('running composer install');

// [Optional] if deploy fails automatically unlock.
after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');

// Migrate database before symlink new release.

before('deploy:symlink', 'cachetool:clear:opcache');

after('deploy:symlink', 'artisan:migrate');


after('deploy:symlink', 'deploy:composer_install');

after('deploy:composer_install', 'artisan:db:seed');



after('deploy:update_code', 'npm:install');
after('npm:install', 'npm:build');
```

Notification from Deployer:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you run composer install on your own box and then deploy to online host?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it in one single command, like you do it with `npm`, so the context has the correct path (your application): `run('cd {{release_path}} && composer install');`

Otherwise `composer install` will be executed on the initial (wrong) path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your `composer.lock` file.

Seems you change only the  `composer.json` and try to update your remote code without having update your `composer.lock` (with a `composer update` or `composer require`).